# Proving the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to figure it out a proof of Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem for myself, but i really don't know how to proceed, how to start investigating a proof. Can you help me with some tips or some motivation for the proof (i'm not asking to show me the proof, just a way, a tip or something). I prove it for finite sets but i don't think the same strategy would work for infinite ones (and adding the premise that the sets are infinite doesn't seem to help very much)
Thanks in advance.

Obs. My attempt so far was to construct a bijective function using the fact that there's  injectives functions from the two sets, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is not a trivial proof. I wouldn't expect someone without quite some experience to come up with the proof all by themselves. Just open a book and read it.

Comment: Curious, because that's an exercise

Comment: @ViniciusL.Deloi Where is "an exercise" to prove the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem?! This is a very involved proof. Perhaps it is given as a series of exercises?

Comment: It's from 'A Problem Book in Real Analysis' (Aksoi, Khamsi)

Comment: Sometimes exercises are given to indicate "this theorem is true, its proof is not as important for our topic". Certainly seems to be the case if this is a book about real analysis.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the axiom of choice? That certainly makes it easier, although still not trivial (just to clarify, SB does **not** need choice: it's provable in ZF alone).

Comment: Search on "dog" in the following, if you want an intuitive presentation of one of the usual proofs but not really any motivation: https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/infinity.pdf

Comment: @PatrickStevens LOL. Thanks for that great link.

Comment: I found Proof Wiki useful in understanding the proof of CBST. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem/Lemma  I used it as a basis of writing my own formal version of the proof at http://dcproof.com/CBS.htm -- a fun and challenging exercise!

Answer (score 2):

There are several proofs. I will give you a few hints for a reasonably intuitive one.

The first point to grasp is that you have somehow got to construct a bijection out of the two injections. So if the two sets are $A,B$ and the two injections are $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ you have to decide what subset $X\subset A$ to use for $f$; then you use $g^{-1}$ on $A\setminus X$. Think about that for a while.

One way is to "trace backwards". So start say with in $a_1\in A$ and then try to find $b_1\in B$ such that $g(b_1)=a_1$. If you can't, then you have to put $a_1$ into $X$. Similarly, if you cannot trace back from $b_1$, ie find $a_2\in A$ such that $f(a_2)=b_1$, then if $g(b_1)=a_3$ you must put $a_3$ into $A\setminus X$. One of three things must happen, either you can trace back indefinitely, or you end up stuck in one set or the other. If you end up stuck, then that determines how all the elements in that chain (up to getting stuck) must be treated. In the indefinite case you have a choice, but must treat the elements in the chain consistently.

Comment: There are many proofs of the theorem. What do you mean by two main ones? I can easily think of at least 4.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ok, maybe that comment was too subjective. I have changed the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was looking to

> construct a bijective function using the fact that there's injectives functions from the two sets

The OP was also asking for the motivation behind it all; I suggest that the following set theory problem is a good starting point.

Problem: Consider the injective function $\sigma: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ mapping

$\quad n \mapsto n + 1$

Show that there is exactly one subset of

$\quad \displaystyle \text{Graph}(\sigma) \cup {\big[\text{Graph}(\sigma)\big]}^{-1}$

that is a bijective correspondence of $\Bbb N$ with itself.

(if $\rho$ is a relation $\rho^{-1}$ is the [converse relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation))

---

For the above problem the two injections are $f = \sigma$ and $g = \sigma$,

$\quad f= \sigma: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$

$\quad g = \sigma: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$